# Missing privilege: fewer CAPTCHAs

Tags: feature-request, privileges

Users past 10,000 reputation see fewer CAPTCHAs but this is not listed in the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/) page.

Comment: Oh really? How so?

Comment: the thread i've elected to close this as a dupe of is more recent, but it's more detailed and contains links to other stuff on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel this needs to be in the privilege pages; it's basically trivia.

Comment: More trivia than "Nominate moderators" that happens maybe once a year, or "View close votes" or "Create wiki posts"?

Comment: Or "Reduced Advertising"

Comment: @Billy, heh, I was going to say "the privileges page is for abilities you gain, not things that just happen" and then I remembered about the reduced ads.

Comment: Fewer CAPTCHAs seems at least as helpful as fewer ads. Why *wouldn't* you list a privelege? It's not like there are too many to fit.